# Convert slice of string input from console to slice of numbers

Tags: go, slice, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a Go script that takes in as many lines of comma-separated coordinates as the user wishes, split and convert the string of coordinates to float64, store each line as a slice, and then append each slice in a slice of slices for later usage.

Example inputs are:

```
1.1,2.2,3.3
3.14,0,5.16
```

Example outputs are:

```
[[1.1 2.2 3.3],[3.14 0 5.16]]
```

The equivalent in Python is

```
def get_input():
    print("Please enter comma separated coordinates:")
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            line = [float(x) for x in line.replace(" ", "").split(",")]
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    return lines
```

But what I wrote in Go seems way too long (pasted below), and I'm creating a lot of variables without the ability to change variable type as in Python. Since I literally just started writing Golang to learn it, I fear my script is long as I'm trying to convert Python thinking into Go. Therefore, I would like to ask for some advice as to how to write this script shorter and more concise in Go style? Thank you.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    inputs := get_input()
    fmt.Println(inputs)
}

func get_input() [][]float64 {
    fmt.Println("Please enter comma separated coordinates: ")

    var inputs [][]float64

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if len(scanner.Text()) > 0 {
            raw_input := strings.Replace(scanner.Text(), " ", "", -1)
            input := strings.Split(raw_input, ",")
            converted_input := str2float(input)
            inputs = append(inputs, converted_input)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    return inputs
}

func str2float(records []string) []float64 {

    var float_slice []float64

    for _, v := range records {
        if s, err := strconv.ParseFloat(v, 64); err == nil {
            float_slice = append(float_slice, s)
        }
    }

    return float_slice
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Golang may be less verbose than plain C, but nearly nothing beats Python for concise code... By the way, it should be longer: you should check for scanner.Err() after the for loop.

Comment: @StephaneMartin, thanks a lot for your comment. I just checked Golang's documentation on Scanner. Do you mean the line `if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil...` should be added to detect any error?

Comment: yep, after the for loop returns, to check that the scanner could actually parse content

Comment: @StephaneMartin Thank you :) Honestly this is my first time solving a problem independently using something other than Python. And it helps me to appreciate the simplicity of Python.

Comment: Coming from Python (I do too), golang is only interesting for speed and goroutines/channels...

Comment: Personally I'm writing some exercises in Java and Go now as I'm too dependent on Python. In what applications are goroutines/channels common?

Comment: Concurrent code. Python is not truely multi-threaded (look for "python global interpreter lock"), so typical pure python code only uses one CPU. Goroutines (aka green threads) in go are multiplexed on OS threads, so the program actually uses all CPUs. Channels are queues to pass objects between goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only string functions:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var result [][]float64
    var txt string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        txt = scanner.Text()
        if len(txt) > 0 {
            values := strings.Split(txt, ",")
            var row []float64
            for _, v := range values {
                fl, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.Trim(v, " "), 64)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Incorrect value for float64 '%v'", v))
                }
                row = append(row, fl)
            }
            result = append(result, row)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", result)
}
```

Run:

```
$ printf "1.1,2.2,3.3
3.14,0,5.16
2,45,76.0, 45 , 69" | go run experiment2.go

Result: [[1.1 2.2 3.3] [3.14 0 5.16] [2 45 76 45 69]]
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for sharing your solution! Really like your idea to write all the input data in command line :)

Answer (score 1):

With given input, you can concatenate them to make a JSON string and then unmarshal (deserialize) that:

```
func main() {
    var lines []string
    for {
        var line string
        fmt.Scanln(&line)
        if line == "" {
            break
        }
        lines = append(lines, "["+line+"]")
    }
    all := "[" + strings.Join(lines, ",") + "]"
    inputs := [][]float64{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(all), &inputs); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(inputs)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kaveh. I've never used JSON with Go and will look into it!